# How to update value progress bar bootstrap from controller in ASP .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, viewmodel, progress

I have a table that receive email of my users for newsletter .I Show it on my dashboard with count .but now I want to show on progress bar and its percentage per last month
how do I do ? I create another view model for show count of some things
I can show count of them but I need show on progress bar too.

my viewmodel:

```c#
       public class NewsLetterViewModel
            {
           
                public string Phone { get; set; }
        
           
                public string Email { get; set; }
         
                public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use ViewBag to pass count and percentage.Here is a demo:

Action:

```
public IActionResult News()
    {
        ViewBag.Count = 0;
        ViewBag.Percentage = 0;
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult News(NewsLetterViewModel n,int Count)
    {
        //you can pass the count and percentage with ViewBag here
        ViewBag.Count= Count+ 1;
        ViewBag.Percentage=25;
        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
 <div>
    Count:@ViewBag.Count
</div>
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: @ViewBag.Percentage%;" aria-valuenow="@ViewBag.Percentage" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">@ViewBag.Percentage%</div>
    </div>
<form  method="post">
    <input hidden name="Count" value="@ViewBag.Count" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Phone" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Phone" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Phone" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Email" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="CreateDate" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="CreateDate" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="CreateDate" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <input type="submit"value="submit" />
</form>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: which tool you use for make gif like this?

Comment: You can search in browser about recording screen to gif,there will be many free tools.